# Is there a way in Azure universal artifacts to display the package description field with line breaks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

This is how the package description is constructed for **azure universal artifacts**

```
    // Universal package Description: <SHA1> <BUILD_URL> <GIT_BRANCH>
    // Limit: 256 characters
    def shaID = env.GIT_COMMIT.substring(0,7)
    def description = "SHA1: ${shaID} BUILD_URL: ${env.BUILD_URL} GIT_BRANCH: ${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
    if( description.length() > 256 ) {
        description = description.substring(0,255)
    }
```

**Azure cli** to publish:

> az artifacts universal publish  --project "XXX" --scope project --feed "ProjectArtifacts" --name "package_name" --version "0.0.1" --path . --description "SHA1: 12345678 BUILD_URL: <url.........................> GIT_BRANCH: dummy_branch"

The description in **Azure** looks like this:

> SHA1: 12345678 BUILD_URL: <url.........
> ................> GIT_BRANCH: dummy_branch

Will it be possible to add line breaks such that the description is more readable.

> SHA1: 12345678
> BUILD_URL: url
> GIT_BRANCH: dummy_branch

Comment: Hi Niraimathi, Did you get a chance to try out below workaround, how did it go?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it cannot be done by passing the description to `--description` attribute of az artifacts command line. If i put the line breaker `\n` into the description string, it will be automatically changed to `\\n`

However, there is workaround to do this in azure devops pipeline. See below:

First i [create a azure pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Cyaml%2Cbrowser%2Ctfs-2018-2), Then i add a powershell task to [set the description as a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts). See below scripts in powershell task:

```
- powershell: |
    #use ";" as delimiter 
    $des= "SHA1: 12345678 ;BUILD_URL: <url.........................> ;GIT_BRANCH: dummy_branch"
    #replace delimiter ";" with "%0D%0A" which will be parsed as "\n"
    $newdes= $des -replace ';', "%0D%0A"

    #set the descrption to environment varialbe Description.
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Description]$newdes"
```

Then i use [UniversalPackages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task to publish to Azure devops feed.

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: Universal Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    vstsFeedPublish: '<projectName>/<feedName>'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: '<Package name>'
    versionOption: custom
    versionPublish: '<Package version>'
    # refer to the description set in above powershell task by setting packagePublishDescription as $(Description)
    packagePublishDescription: '$(Description)'
```

See below screenshot of the description published by above pipeline.

[image]

You can also s[ubmit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to microsoft development team regarding this issue.